# Pegar e guardar uma Classe especificando apenas o inicio dela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, tudo bem?
Eu gostaria de armazenar em uma variável, dentre varias classes deste exemplo, a classe que começa com **VITRINE**. **Não quero armazenar o html**. Quero armazenar **o nome da classe**!

```
<a class = "classe1 classe2 vitrine-12457" href="link01">Conteudo 1</a>
<a class = "classe1 vitrine-12458 classe3" href="link02">conteudo 2</a>
<a class = "classe1 vitrine-12459 classe3 classe4" href="link03">Conteudo 3</a>
```

O meu objetivo é por exemplo, através de script, criar um novo elemento e dar um append colocando-o dentro da tag < a > repetindo o link respectivo de cada tag. O resultado ficaria + - assim:

```
<a class = "classe1 classe2 vitrine-12457" href="link01">Conteudo 1
   <span href="link01">
      conteudo do span
   </span>
</a>
<a class = "classe1 vitrine-12458 classe3" href="link02">conteudo 2
   <span href="link02">
      conteudo do span
   </span>
</a>
<a class = "classe1 vitrine-12459 classe3 classe4" href="link03">Conteudo 3
   <span href="link01">
      conteudo do span
   </span>
</a>
```

No meu reciocínio... armazenando a unica classe que difere das outras, eu consigo passa-la pro Jquery por aglutinação e assim, tanto conseguir pegar a href como também o elemento correto e Atribuir a um filho, o mesmo href do elemento Pai.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Mas você vai fazer uma query para encontrar um elemento e armazenar o nome da classe para então fazer outra query para encontrar novamente o elemento que você já tinha encontrado? Coloque o código que você pretende utilizar com um comentário na parte que está faltando.

Comment: Sua pergunta está pouco clara. Por favor, explique melhor o que deseja fazer (tente utilizar outras palavras).

Comment: Eu editei! Acho que ficou mais claro... ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, para buscar todos os elementos que contenha uma classe contendo determinada palavra você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
let elementos = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class*="vitrine"]')];
```

Desta forma, em **elementos** você terá um array com todos os objetos que possuem alguma classe contento *vitrine* no nome. Daí pode fazer um filtro para retornar o que precisa.

Porém, acredito que seria melhor você usar o atributo personalizado data, como:

```
<a href="#"... data-vitrine="1234">bllbl</a>
```

Mas claro que isso deve ser considerado no seu contexto. Me pergunto porque você não busca o elemento exatamente pela classe que precisa ao invés de agrupar as semelhanças antes...
Espero que ajude.

Comment: Essa query só irá funcionar se o atributo `class` começar com `vitrine`. Não funciona se `vitrine` estiver declarado no meio da classe. Para este caso seria necessário utilizar `class*="vitrine"`.

Comment: Você está certíssimo. Falta de atenção minha. Obrigado pela correção. Editando a resposta para corrigir a informação.

Comment: Isso também funciona atribuindo um seletor css? tipo: querySelector("#listagemProdutos[class*="vitrine"])?

Comment: Sim, você pode implementar a política de seletor que precisar no querySelector.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado! :>